# QML: Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    property string rootName: "--rootName"

    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 400

    title: qsTr("WatchFace Maker")

    WatchLcd{
        property string watchLcdInApp: "watchLcdInApp"
        id: watchLcd
    }

    TextAdder{
        id: textAdder

        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("APP: ", root.watchLcd.watchLcdInApp)//#Error!!! remove root, it works.
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know:

1. Why it doesn't work when I add root id in above commented line?
2. How do children component access sibling component's property if children component is created from a XXX.qml file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `id` property is a "special kind" of property, it is only resolved at "code time" and cannot be resolved during runtime.

`root.watchLcd` will not work because `watchLcd` is an `id`, and as such it can't be resolved with `root.watchLcd`

The `id` also logically works only in that particular source, and you only need that particular `id` regardless of the structure of the object tree, you don't need its parent `id` as in `root.watchLcd`

If you want to access a specific object from another file, naturally, this can't happen through its `id`. You can either use a property or a function for it:

```
//SomeItem.qml
Item {
  property alias text : obj.text
  Item  {
    id: obj
    property string text
  }
  property Item object : obj
  function getObj() { return obj }
}

/main.qml
Window {
  visible: true

  SomeItem {
    id: item
    text: "someText"
  }

  SomeItem {
    Component.onCompleted: {
      //console.log(item.obj.text) // TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
      console.log(item.object.text) // someText
      console.log(item.getObj().text) // someText
    }
  }
}
```

Also, note how the `property alias` works - it may be useful in many cases, if all you need to access is a nested object's property you can expose it with an alias without needing access to the object externally.