# QML Javascript Dictionary of Property Alias not Updating

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

My question is the following:

Do changes to the javascript dictionary values not modify the actual value that is mapped, but rather its own internal copy?  Is there a way to get around this?

I have a javascript dictionary that contains property aliases of an object.
When I assign them values, the objects in the dictionary itself changes but it does not propagate outward to the actual display that I want to change.

I have had this problem before, placing the dot access outside of the dictionary access fixed it.  However, I cannot do it this time around due to the fact that you cannot dot access using `.text` because it produces error of cannot read property of undefined.

[QML: Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736573/qml-cannot-read-property-xxx-of-undefined)

My code resembles something of the following example, I had it obscured to protect actual info so sorry if it is a cringy example.
onUpdate passes in another dictionary that I want to tie to the local .qml dictionary.

**ControllerDisplay.qml**

```
// ...
property alias id1: id_box.text
// ...
SomeBox
{
  id: id_box
  text: "some text"
}
```

**main.qml**

```
ControllerDisplay{
  id: controller
}

// ...

Connections
{
  target: myguimodel
  onUpdate:
  {
    var dict = { "ID1" : controller.id1}
    for (var key in updates)
    {
      dict[key] = updates[key] // does NOT change the value in ControllerDisplay
      controller.id1 = updates[key] // DOES change the value ControllerDisplay

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Comment: I'm going to guess a little, but the following will happen: If you have a `property var obj: new Object()` and then in a function you do `obj.foo='bar'`, it won't be visible until you also do `obj = obj` after you have set field `foo`.  Anyways, this may give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `var dict = { "ID1" : controller.id1}`, you store the value of `controller.id1`, not a reference to it.

If you want to be able to modify it you could do:

```
var dict = { "ID1": { "object": controller, "property": "id1"}};
for (var key in updates) {
    var target = dict[key];
    target.object[target.property] = updates[key];
}
```

This whole code doesn't look really QML idiomatic though. I would try using property binding if I were you.